# Get previous result from association loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a association loop that I need to get the previous record of a particular object. The method [index-1] isn't working for me.

I'm looking to get the previous assessmentDate.

**View**

```
<% @trial.assessments.order("assessment_date ASC").group(:assessment_id).each_with_index do |e, index| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= e.assessmentDate[index-1] %></td>
  <% e.establishments.order(:selection_id).group(:selection_id).each do |f| %>
  <td><%= f.total.round(1) %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

**Associations**

```
has_many :establishments, primary_key: 'assessment_id'
belongs_to :assessment, primary_key: 'assessment_id', optional: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looping over assessments, but then using the assessment index on assessmentDate. Perhaps this is what you mean instead?

```
<%
  assessments = @trial.assessments.order("assessment_date ASC").group(:assessment_id).to_a
  assessments.each_with_index do |e, index| 
%>
  <tr>
  <td><%= assessments[index-1].assessmentDate if i > 0 %></td>
  <% e.establishments.order(:selection_id).group(:selection_id).each do |f| %>
  <td><%= f.total.round(1) %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the quick response @bkimble.